# semantic versions for the wheel file contains devNN

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-wheel, python-pbr

I'm trying to create a python package with the following *python setup.py bdist_wheel*. The wheel file is generated under *my_py_lib-0.0.2.dev19-py2.py3-none-any.whl*. The semantic version is appearing as 0.0.2.dev19. However the **dev19** is also appearing.
How do i remove this value if dev19 ?

Relevant files are given below

setup.py file below

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr>=1.9', 'setuptools>=17.1'],
    pbr=True
)
```

setup.cfg file's relevant sections below

```
[metadata]
name = my-py-lib
version = 0.0.2
author = My Name
author_email = tbd@tbd.com
summary = tbd
description_file = README.md
license = Apache-2
home_page = https://git-loc.tbd/group/my-py-lib
classifiers =
    Development Status :: 4 - Beta
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    Intended Audience :: Information Technology
    License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
    Operating System :: Unix
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6
 
[options]
include_package_data = true
zip_safe = false
install_requires = requests;pprintpp;
 
[files]
packages = my-py-lib
 
[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1
```

Comment: Maybe it is because of `pbr`...?

Comment: thanks!. I removed the pbr=True value and now the devNN tag is not appearing.

Comment: In this case, `pbr` can be removed from `setup_requires` as well. -- Also it seems like the whole `setup_requires` can be removed from `setup.py`.

Comment: I did a little more digging around and found a resolution with pbr=True. Will post the resolution below. Thanks @sinroc. The hint that pbr may be the case of the issue really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ***pbr*** uses the latest git tag to determine the version number. In my original project, I did not have a git tag and as a result the value of *version = 0.0.2* from the setup.cfg was being used and 0.0.2.dev19 was created. 
Now, I'd created a git tag with command. `git tag v0.0.2`
After creation of the .devM tag is removed and the semantic version mentioned in the git tag is considered. The value in [metadata] of setup.cfg section is commented out. The version is directly picked up from the semantic version tag. 
Reference: [pbr features link](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/features.html)